# How can I make python's argparse accept any number of [-R a b]s, and aggregate them into a list

Tags: python, argparse

I want to be able to call `foo.py -R a b -R c d -R e f` and get something like `[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')]` in a variable.  I can instead use `foo.py -R a=b -R c=d -R e=f` and do the splitting manually, but I'd rather not do this, because I'm building a wrapper around another program and would like to mimic it's command line option input format.

I have tried the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Foo')
parser.add_argument('-R', metavar=('A', 'B'), dest='libnames', type=str, default=('.', 'Top'), nargs=2)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = parser.parse_args()
    print(args.libnames)
```

but then I get `['e', 'f']` when I call it as `foo.py -R a b -R c d -R e f`.

Comment: Using `action='append' should produce `[['a', 'b'], ['c', 'd'], ['e', 'f']]`.  That's close, a list of lists, rather than a list of tuples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom `argparse.Action` class.

https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#argparse.Action

```
import argparse

class Pairs(argparse.Action):
    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, opts, **kwargs):
        lst = getattr(namespace, self.dest)
        if lst is None:
            lst = []
            setattr(namespace, self.dest, lst)
        lst.append(tuple(values))

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()   
parser.add_argument('-R', nargs='+', dest='libnames', action=Pairs)
print parser.parse_args("-R a b -R c d -R e f".split())
```

output:

```
Namespace(libnames=[('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f')])
```

Comment: I believe you mean `class Pairs`, instead of `def Pairs`, since only classes can subclass another class. Otherwise, +1 to this solution. However, please completely adapt this example to the OP's scenario, for completeness sake.